# Show only link to file which exists Django Python

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a four FileFields in my models.py like 2 below:

```
file_1 = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='PN_datoteke/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name="Datoteka 1")
file_2 = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='PN_datoteke/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name="Datoteka 2")
```

Each time different number of files is uploaded and some are left empty. I use following in my .html page to offer a download option of the file which is uploaded:

```
<p class="article-content mb-1"><strong>Datoteka 1: </strong><a href="{{post.file_1.url}}" download>Preuzmi</a></p>
<p class="article-content mb-1"><strong>Datoteka 2: </strong><a href="{{post.file_2.url}}" download>Preuzmi</a></p>
```

Problem is, I have 4 upload options and if some are not used I get following error:

```
The 'file_2' attribute has no file associated with it
```

How can I suppress the empty fields (.destroy, .remove) before they are generated on the page, if file doesn't exist? I guess I must use a javascript? How to check and not display a

if a file doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript won't help you here as the error occurs at the server side during rendering. You can simply put the HTML for the file in an [`if` template tag [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#if):

```
{% if post.file_1 %}
    <p class="article-content mb-1"><strong>Datoteka 1: </strong><a href="{{post.file_1.url}}" download>Preuzmi</a></p>
{% endif %}
{% if post.file_2 %}
    <p class="article-content mb-1"><strong>Datoteka 2: </strong><a href="{{post.file_2.url}}" download>Preuzmi</a></p>
{% endif %}
```